# Getting stuck in for loop i think, cannot use variables set outside of loop?

Tags: ios, variables, loops, for-loop, global-variables

ok so my program seem to be running fine and doing all the calculation i need, the last piece the program need is an incrementing cut list. So i have tried to build an NSMutable array and use previously set variables, which i will eventually populate a table with. only when i run the code and hit the calculate button, the program freezes, and nothing shows in NSLOG etc.
can i not use previous variables set outside the for loop? or whats going on?

```
-(IBAction)calculateGo
{
    BuildNavAppDelegate *buildNavDelegate = (BuildNavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    float iridge = ([ridge.text intValue]);
    float ihip = ([hip.text intValue]);
    float ispacing = ([rafterSpace.text intValue]);

    float floatTLPMR = [buildNavDelegate.TLPMR floatValue];
    int floatRafter = [buildNavDelegate.raftThicknessPassed intValue];
    int comraftbird = [buildNavDelegate.comRaftBirdPassed intValue];

    float mitre = (45 * M_PI) / 180;
    float y = tanf(mitre);
    float mitreThickness = sqrt((y*y)+1) * ihip;

    float TLRafterSpace = (floatTLPMR * ispacing);

    float firstCreeper =  (TLRafterSpace + (mitreThickness/2))-(floatRafter/2);
    firstCreep.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f", firstCreeper];

    float comSetBack = floatTLPMR * (iridge/2);
    comRaftSetBack.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f", comSetBack];

    float crownSetBack = (floatTLPMR * (floatRafter/2));
    crownEndSetBack.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f", crownSetBack];

    creeperArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

for (int x = firstCreeper; x <= comraftbird; x + TLRafterSpace) {
[creeperArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuck in an infinite loop because you forgot to increment the value of `x`:

```
for (int x = firstCreeper; x <= comraftbird; x + TLRafterSpace)
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That should probably be:

```
for (int x = firstCreeper; x <= comraftbird; x += TLRafterSpace)
```